# Re-Ordering Controls in a FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, flowlayoutpanel

Evening Everyone,

I've spent a little time trying to figure this one out and I have hit a wall. I am trying to re-order existing UserControls in a FlowLayoutPanel.

Usage...
I have a form that contains a FlowLayoutPanel, in that panel, there are multiple UserControls that have their own events and when they have completed their own task, they change the value of the UserControl Tag. Each value is unique and is not repeated (I have verified this by iterating through each control in the panel).

How does one re-order these?

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        FlowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout()
        FlowLayoutPanel1.TabStop = True
        Dim p As Integer = 0
        Dim rp As Integer = 0
        For Each r As Control In FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls
            listC(p) = r.Tag
            p += 1
        Next
        For i = 0 To listC.Count
            If listC(i) = 0 Then Exit For
            For Each c As Control In FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls
                If c.Tag = listC(i) Then
                    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(c, rp)
                    c.TabStop = True
                    c.TabIndex = rp
                    rp += 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next
        FlowLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout()
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Refresh()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is off the top of my head but I think that I'd be doing it like this:

```vb
Dim children = FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.
                                Cast(Of Control)().
                                OrderBy(Function(c) CInt(c.Tag)).
                                ToArray()

For i = 0 To children.GetUpperBound(0)
    Dim child = children(i)

    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(child, i)
Next
```

Get all the child controls into an array first, sorted by that `Tag` value, then loop through that array and set the index within the `FlowLayoutPanel` to the index within the array. You mustn't enumerate a collection and modify that collection at the same time. That's what you're doing here:

```vb
For Each c As Control In FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls
    '...
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(c, rp)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my flaw, what you proposed worked like a dream. I should of know better, guess this is what happens when you work to many hours! Have a Happy Thanksgiving!

Comment: @DavidsLearnin, if this answer resolves your issue, please accept it by clicking the check mark. That will show everyone that you need no more assistance without their actually opening the question. It also helps other searching for solutions to similar problems.